# visual side by side text comparison tool/routine for use in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, algorithm

I am sure a general routine, or library must exists to do this, but I need to be able to show the user a "before" and "after" comparison of two versions of a string/text file.

For example the old visual source safe had a great tool where it show both files and highlighted the adds, deletes and changes.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel, anyone know of a routine in VB or C# that I could use or use as a starting point? If not, is there a general search term for this types of comparisons so that I can search for one myself...not sure what to call it, so have had a hard time google-ing it...

BTW: These will be rendered as HTML in an asp.net app.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a diff algorithm
I would read [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) and its algorithms. There was [another discussion](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.109148.6) about it on another forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a VS plugin, but perhaps you're looking for something like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for an actual algorithm that I can build off of to use in my own app, but thanks.